# Heroku push rejected, Failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: heroku

I am unsure why my deployment to heroku is failing. could one please advise me.
i followed this but no success same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574176/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-install-gems-via-bundler

read documentation but still unable to resolve issue:

```
Enumerating objects: 149, done.
Counting objects: 100% (149/149), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (112/112), done.
Writing objects: 100% (112/112), 969.78 KiB | 7.08 MiB/s, done.
Total 112 (delta 88), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.7
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem byebug (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once (per group).
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        zeitwerk-2.3.0 requires ruby version >= 2.4.4, which is incompatible with the
remote:        current version, ruby 2.3.7p456
remote:        Bundler Output: Your Gemfile lists the gem byebug (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once (per group).
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        zeitwerk-2.3.0 requires ruby version >= 2.4.4, which is incompatible with the
remote:        current version, ruby 2.3.7p456
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to openheavens.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/openheavens.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/openheavens.git'
```

gemlock file

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.1)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.1)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.1)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.2.1)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.1)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
    activerecord (6.0.2.1)
      activemodel (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
    activestorage (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.1)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.2)
    acts_as_commentable (4.0.2)
    awesome_print (1.8.0)
    aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
    babel-source (5.8.35)
    babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
      babel-source (>= 4.0, < 6)
      execjs (~> 2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.1)
    carrierwave (1.3.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    ckeditor (4.3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
      terrapin
    climate_control (0.2.0)
    cloudinary (1.13.2)
      aws_cf_signer
      rest-client
    coderay (1.1.2)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
    crass (1.0.6)
    devise (4.7.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.12.2)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.1)
    foundation-rails (6.6.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.3.0)
      sprockets-es6 (>= 0.9.0)
    friendly_id (5.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    http-accept (1.7.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (1.8.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.10.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.4.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2019.1009)
    mimemagic (0.3.4)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.14.0)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.9)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (1.2.3)
    pry (0.13.0)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    pry-byebug (3.9.0)
      byebug (~> 11.0)
      pry (~> 0.13.0)
    puma (3.12.4)
    rack (2.2.2)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.2.1)
      actioncable (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      actiontext (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.1)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.1)
      activemodel (= 6.0.2.1)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.1)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.2.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    responders (3.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    rest-client (2.1.0)
      http-accept (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    simple_calendar (2.3.0)
      rails (>= 3.0)
    simple_form (5.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-es6 (0.9.2)
      babel-source (>= 5.8.11)
      babel-transpiler
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.2)
    terrapin (0.6.0)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.7)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.7)
    warden (1.2.8)
      rack (>= 2.0.6)
    web-console (4.0.1)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    zeitwerk (2.3.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  acts_as_commentable
  awesome_print
  byebug
  carrierwave (~> 1.0)
  ckeditor (~> 4.2)
  cloudinary
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  devise
  font-awesome-rails
  foundation-rails
  friendly_id (~> 5.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  pg
  pry-byebug
  puma (~> 3.0)
  rails (= 6.0.2.1)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  simple_calendar (~> 2.0)
  simple_form
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '6.0.2.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0"
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```